# Book references for combinatory logic as applied in Haskell?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell, combinatory-logic

I am looking for book references on combinatory logic. Is there a book focused on how combinatory logic is applied in the context of pure functional languages like Haskell?

I found ["Combinators: A Centennial View"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.12811) by Stephen Wolfram (2021), but it has too much advertising in it. Every second page Wolfram tries to sell the reader his programming language. Is there any well-written book with less advertisement?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but you could do a lot worse than to go through the relevant sections of *[The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/1987/01/slpj-book-1987.pdf)* by Simon Peyton-Jones, particularly the chapter on SK combinators. The book is now free.